Which BHC error correction code produces non-zero code for all-zero data input
I am reversing a raw flash image (Micron MT29F16G08ABACA), and I am currently stuck trying to find the correct ECC algorithm.
What I know thus far:

1 page = 4096 bytes data + 224 bytes OOB (out of band) data
The 224 OOB consists of 32 bytes unknown data and 192 bytes (8 * 24) of ECC data
The 4096 bytes page is split in 512 byte sections, every section corresponding to 24 bytes of ECC data
According to the datasheet, the ECC algorithm can correct up to 8 bits per section of 540 bytes (512 + 24 ECC + 4 byte unknown OOB).


Minimum required ECC 8-bit ECC per 540 bytes of data


A block of 512 zero bytes results in ECC 13 79 62 F8 E0 97 77 B9 C5 AD 81 19 81 DE 84 BF 18 B6 54 53 B4 79 21 42
A block of 512 FF bytes results in ECC full of FF.

My guess would be a BCH ECC algorithm. But all BHC algorithms I could find result in an all-zero ECC code corresponding with an all-zero data input.
I did find this relevant github project (github.com/cyberdong/bch_encoder_decoder), which appears to contain a leaked ECC algorithm for the same family of Micron Nand Flash devices.
But even this encoder is generating an all-zero ECC code for an all-zero data input.
Which ECC algorithm could this be?
Is it possible to have a BCH encoder to generate a non-zero ECC code for an all-zero data input?
